# How to make database connectivity in Java using JDBC API?

Tags: java, jdbc

How to create a jdbc connection in Java?

Answer (score 7):

To create a connection, you need to *load the driver* first. For example, for MySQL:

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
```

The driver class to load obviously depends on the JDBC driver (and thus on the database) that needs to be on the classpath.

Then, *make the connection*:

```
String url = "jdbc:mysql://host_name:port/dbname";
String user = "scott";
String pwd = "tiger";
Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, pwd);
```

The `url` is the "connection url" and identifies the database to connect to. Again, the syntax will depend on the JDBC driver you're using. So, refer to the documentation of your JDBC driver.

[Establishing a Connection](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/jdbc/basics/connecting.html) in The Java Tutorials is indeed a good reference.

Comment: Good answer, too bad this question is disliked.

Answer (score 5):

See [sun's jdbc tutorial for begginers](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/jdbc/overview/index.html)

Particularly http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/jdbc/basics/connecting.html

> First, you need to establish a
>   connection with the DBMS you want to
>   use. Typically, a JDBC™ application
>   connects to a target data source using
>   one of two mechanisms:
>
> DriverManager:   This fully
>   implemented class requires an
>   application to load a specific driver,
>   using a hardcoded URL. As part of its
>   initialization, the DriverManager
>   class attempts to load the driver
>   classes referenced in the jdbc.drivers
>   system property. This allows you to
>   customize the JDBC Drivers used by
>   your applications.
>
> DataSource:   This interface is
>   preferred over DriverManager because
>   it allows details about the underlying
>   data source to be transparent to your
>   application. A DataSource object's
>   properties are set so that it
>   represents a particular data source.

```
Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection
           ( "jdbc:myDriver:wombat", "myLogin","myPassword");
```

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [ABCs of JDBC](http://java.dzone.com/articles/jdbc-faq-getting-started).

Comment: @Tom: Or simple as do re mi...

Answer (score -1):

To create a jdbc connection in java , you need to know about some classes and interfaces required to establish a connection which are provided in java.sql package.

Classes are Drivermanager and Types.

Interfaces are Connection, Statement, PreparedStatement, CallableStatement, ResultSet...etc

This is the program to establish a jdbc connection

```
import java.sql.*;
class Sssm
{
public static void main(String aaa[])throws SqlException
{
Drivermanager d=new oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver();
DriverManager.getconnection(d);
Connection c=Drivermanager.getconnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe","scott","tiger");
c.close();
}
}
```

**Note** : Instead of scott and tiger.. please write the login credentials that you have provided for oracle database.