# Establishing a JDBC connection for java application

Tags: java, jar, classpath

I'm trying to establish a JDBC connection following the steps below for the Twitter driver:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tJ7n8.png)

I have:

- the JDBC URL
- the driver class

Can someone explain me how to add the driver JAR to the classpath and how to establish a connection (so where to put the JDBC URL and driver class).

Thanks!

Comment: are running on console or you using any IDE

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make database connectivity in Java using JDBC API?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2710303/how-to-make-database-connectivity-in-java-using-jdbc-api)

Comment: Do you know how to use Google?

Comment: @shivam I'm using eclipse

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt oK thanks! But it doesnt explain how to add the JAR driver into classpath. Any idea?

Comment: Answer should not depend on Eclipse.  Get a better IDE - IntelliJ.  Neither one will help once you deploy.  The answers on what is best depend on whether this is a desktop or web app.

Comment: @duffymo I edited my question

Comment: @tararam - You should put the JAR and license file in a /lib folder that you add to your Eclipse CLASSPATH.  That'll take care of compile time and running inside Eclipse.  When you package and deploy your app, without Eclipse, you have to add that JAR to the CLASSPATH at runtime.  You can do this using -cp argument to java.exe OR use Maven to create an executable JAR with dependencies packaged inside it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Right click on project -> Build Path -> Configure build path -> Add external jar

try {
     Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
     Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@<hostname>:<port num>:<DB name>"
                ,"user","password");
     Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
     System.out.println("Created DB Connection....");
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: edited my question